# Opening PDF and image in new tab in React from binary file

Tags: reactjs, binaryfiles

I am trying to open a file from server that is binary in new tab in browser when its type is PDF or image. So, I pass fileContent (binary content of my file on server and filetype)..new tab opens but I get an error:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
  const handleViewFile = (filetype, fileContent) => {
if (filetype === "pdf") {
  const blob = new Blob([fileContent], { type: "application/pdf" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url, "_blank");
} else if (
  filetype === "jpg" ||
  filetype === "png" ||
  filetype === "jpeg"
) {
  const blob = new Blob([fileContent], { type: `image/${filetype}` });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

};

I also tried with btoa and base64 encoding, yet it didn't work.